# SVG.js: Detecting if an `Element` is a `Group`

Tags: typescript, svg.js

I need to determine if an element retrieved via `SVG.get()` is a group (`SVG.G`). I thought this would be a simple `instanceof` check, but I'm getting a `never` type error in Typescript.

Here's the code:

```
    // Get the element from the <defs> section
    const newuse = svg.get(key);
    // Set the fill colour
    const fill = "red";
    // If it's a group, go through and fill all children with the "data- playerfill" attribute
    if ( newuse instanceof svg.G ) {
        // I have to do this in Typescript because the Set doesn't have a "fill" function defined
        (newuse as svg.G).select("[data-playerfill=true]").each(function(this: svg.Element) { this.fill(fill); });
    } else {
        // Just a single element that you fill
        newuse.fill(fill);
    }                            }
```

The problem is that I get the following error on that last line:

`Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'never'.`

From what I can tell, this means that the else clause is never evaluated. But I'm not sure why. Are *all* `SVG.Element` also `SVG.G`? I sure didn't think so.

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround here is to not use `instanceof`. Use the `is()` method in SVG.js (v2.7.1, anyway).

`if (x.is(SVG.G))`

Answer (score 1):

the instanceof test should now work correctly in 3.0.12 since Svg.G is now correctly declared to be a class.